# How can I retrieve data within my widget

Tags: plugins, widgets

I have a Widget which I am creating but my quesiton is how do I access my custom table which I created via my plugin. I am attempting to fill the dropdown from the table called tfp which contains the column liters which I wish to popluate the values into the drop down

```
class my_plugin extends WP_Widget {

// constructor
function my_plugin() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Thomsons Fuels Widget', 'wp_widget_plugin') );

}

// widget form creation
function form($instance) {

//Check values
if( $instance) {
 $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
 $dropdown= esc_attr($instance['dropdown']);
 $textarea = $instance['textarea'];
 } else {
 $title = '';
 $textarea = '';
}
?>


<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dropdown'); ?>">
<?php _e('Liters',   'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

</p>
```

How I created the table in the plugin

```
global $wpdb;
global $custom_table_example_db_version;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tfp'; // do not forget about tables prefix

// sql to create your table
// NOTICE that:
// 1. each field MUST be in separate line
// 2. There must be two spaces between PRIMARY KEY and its name
//    Like this: PRIMARY KEY[space][space](id)
// otherwise dbDelta will not work
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  liters VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  price VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
  postcodearea varchar(20) NULL,      
  dft varchar(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);";

// we do not execute sql directly
// we are calling dbDelta which cant migrate database
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);

// save current database version for later use (on upgrade)
add_option('custom_table_example_db_version', $custom_table_example_db_version);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read: 
[`SELECT_a_Column`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column)

```
$sql = "SELECT 'liters' FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "tfp";

$liters = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
if( $liters ) { 
  foreach( $liters as $liter ) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $liter . '">' . $liter . '</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: their must be an error in this as liter is showing up in the description element of the drop down box